# Cannot get user input from text box to change box backgroundColor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the user input from the text box to change the background box color for my assignment.
I have been playing with this for a while, however, it only works when I set the box value to colorInput.

```
document.getElementById("box").value;
```

```
document.getElementById("box").value;
```

HTML:

```
<label for="colorInput">Enter a Color:</label>
        <input id="colorInput" type="text">
        <button id="submitColor" type="button">Submit Color</button>
        <div id="box" class="box"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
/** Question 2 */
function submitColor() {
    document.getElementById("submitColor").onclick = function() {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("box").value;
        if (inputVal.value == "yellow") {
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        } else if(inputVal.value == "red") {
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }

    }
}
submitColor();
```

Comment: Your `box` element is a `<div>`, they do not have `.value` properties. You should be getting the value from your `colorInput` `<input>` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Comment: Is `document.getElementById("box").value` wrong? should it be `document.getElementById("colorInput").value`?

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this was the culprit sorry for the careless error.

Answer (score 1):

A few things going on here:

First - your `var inputVal = document.getElementById("box").value;` is getting the value of the `<div>`? I believe that line wants to read `var inputVal = document.getElementById("colorInput").value;`

Second - your `<div>` that you are trying to change the background color of currently takes up 0px. You need to either give it a size via CSS or put some content between in the `<div></div>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputVal = document.getElementById("colorInput"); fixed my answer
```